# Android WebView input type="text" cursor not showing

Tags: android, webview

When I click an input text field `(input type="text")` in my WebView, the field shows soft keyboard but the cursor is not showing.
I can type in texts, but no cursor... 
When that happens, Logcat says `"W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection" or "W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection".`
I tried to `override` my WebView making `onCheckIsTextEditor() return true;`, but nothing works.
Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved this problem by setting focusable to the WebView's enclosing view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/web_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    <include
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        layout="@layout/progress_bar"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Just for the record - it helped me fix issue with Samsung Galaxy S3 WebView for Instagram log in process.

Comment: I was looking for it for a long time, thanks. But `focusable` was enough for me, actually removing `focusableInTouchMode` made the touch-to-select a lot smoother!

Answer (score 0):

It may happens because of cursor color. You can make your own custom cursor.

Create an XML file in drawable folder `color_cursor.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <size android:width="2dp" />
    <solid android:color="@color/cp_red"  />
</shape>
```

And use this property

```
<item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@drawable/color_cursor</item>
```

Comment: I didn't know that there was a way to change the cursor color. However, changing cursor color didn't work for me. Thank you anyway for the suggestion.